# $rootScope variable in directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to access a variable from my `$rootScope` in a directives template. However, I can't access it.

The simplified template:

```
<div class="item">
    {{ serverRoot }}
</div>
```

And the directive:

```
ItemModule.directive('item', [function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            item: '='
        },

        templateUrl: 'js/modules/items/directives/templates/item.html',

        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        }
    };
}])
```

How can I access the variable `$rootScope.serverRoot`?

Comment: btw rather define ItemModule.directive('item', ['$rootscope', function ($rootScope) {, or use a grunt task to avoid issues when minifying javascript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have defined a new scope for your directive with

```
scope: {
    item: '='
},
```

So it won't be part of your link -> scope or controller -> scope. You should be able to access it via

```
link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
    scope.serverRoot = $rootScope.serverRoot;    
}
```

Further, your actual directive declaration needs to look like

```
ItemModule.directive('item', [ '$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<div class="item">
    {{ $parent.myServerRoot }}
</div>
```

Although this works, I prefer Brad's solution (+1).

Comment: Actually, there's a benefit to this method because it adds a watcher to `myServerRoot`. If you're waiting for data to load, this is easier. You could, of course, add a watcher within the directive itself, too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
  scope.myServerRoot = $rootScope.serverRoot;
}
```

and in the HTML

```
<div class="item">
    {{ myServerRoot }}
</div>
```